# How to subtract rows where column factor matches using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm moving to dplyr for much of my [data wrangling](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf), but I can't figure out how to do a row-diff based on a factor with it.

I can use ddply from plyr as follows:

```
ddply(.data = df, .variables = .(the_factor), .fun = summarise, diff = diff(the_number))

  the_factor    diff
1        169   0.000
2        169   0.000
3        372  22.557
4        372   0.000
5        372 -19.491
6        372   2.940
7        372  -2.767
8        372  -5.310
9        508   0.000
```

Source data:

```
df <- structure(list(the_factor = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("166", 
"169", "276", "372", "409", "508", "523", "714", "846", "876", 
"969"), class = "factor"), the_date = structure(c(4L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 
8L, 6L, 9L), .Label = c("2012-05-19 21:27:00", "2012-08-02 03:49:00", 
"2012-08-02 03:50:00", "2012-08-02 03:52:00", "2012-08-02 08:36:00", 
"2013-03-15 03:38:00", "2013-03-15 03:40:00", "2013-03-15 03:41:00", 
"2013-03-15 09:14:00", "2013-04-24 13:45:00", "2013-09-04 09:17:00", 
"2014-03-12 14:21:00", "2014-03-12 19:45:00", "2014-03-13 04:51:00", 
"2014-03-13 21:04:00", "2014-03-14 01:18:00", "2014-03-14 04:49:00", 
"2014-03-14 12:09:00"), class = "factor"), the_number = c(0.02, 
17.443, 40, 40, 20.509, 23.449, 20.682, 15.372, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 1.74, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02)), .Names = c("the_factor", 
"the_date", "the_number"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you looking for `group_by(df, the_factor) %>%
    transmute(diff = c(0, diff(the_number)))` ?

Comment: That's more elegant than the "pure" dplyr call which I believe would be something like `mutate(df, diff = lead(the_number) - the_number) %>% select(the_factor, diff)` which leaves an NA at the end.

Comment: Thank you both, these work nicely!

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to do this is to use [`reframe()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/reframe.html), with `.by =`:

```
reframe(df, diff = diff(the_number), .by = the_factor) # one liner!
```

Output:

```
  the_factor    diff
1        169   0.000
2        169   0.000
3        372  22.557
4        372   0.000
5        372 -19.491
6        372   2.940
7        372  -2.767
8        372  -5.310
9        508   0.000
```